# Script for fetching AD users stopped working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been using the following code for over 16 months and all of the sudden $ldapresult is empty.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”}) -eq $null) {

}

$SearchBase = "OU=Active-Users,DC=Rubber,DC=Maid"
$LdapServer = "YYYDC12XYZ.Rubber.Maid"
$ADAccount = "sjones"
Get-ADDomainController -server $ldapserver          

$LDAPResult = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $searchbase -SearchScope 'subtree' -Server $ldapserver -filter "Account -like '*$ADAccount*'" -Properties * | Select -Property AccountExpirationDate, userAccountControl
$pair1, $pair2 = $LDAPResult -replace '^@{|}$' -split '; '
$null, $AccountExpirationDate = $pair1 -split '=', 2
$null, $userAccountControl = $pair2 -split '=', 2    

write-host $ADAccount $AccountExpirationDate $userAccountControl -foregroundcolor "green"   
write-host $LDAPResult
```

So I ran the following command and sure enough it's bringing all the data for sjones. Any idea why the above code would not work anymore?

```
Get-ADUser $ADAccount -Properties * | Select *
```

Comment: Is `YYYDC12XYZ.Rubber.Maid` still an existing domain controller?

Comment: Yes. I verify it using get-addomaincontroller and it resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the attribute in your filter is not correct `-filter "Account -like '*$ADAccount*'"`
Replace "Account" in your filter by "SamAccountName" like this:

```
-Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$ADAccount*'"
```

Comment: That did the trick. The AD people must not be populating Account anymore thus it explains why i was not get any results. Thanks Cavalli